# How to call super method when overriding a method through a trait

Tags: scala, polymorphism, mixins, traits

It would appear that it is possible to change the implementation of a method on a class with a trait such as follows:

```
trait Abstract { self: Result =>
    override def userRepr = "abstract"
}

abstract class Result {
    def userRepr: String = "wtv"
}

case class ValDefResult(name: String) extends Result {
    override def userRepr = name
}

val a = new ValDefResult("asd") with Abstract
a.userRepr
```

Live code is available here: http://www.scalakata.com/52534e2fe4b0b1a1c4daa436

But now I would like to call the previous or super implementation of the function such as follows:

```
trait Abstract { self: Result =>
    override def userRepr = "abstract" + self.userRepr
}
```

or

```
trait Abstract { self: Result =>
    override def userRepr = "abstract" + super.userRepr
}
```

However, none of these alternatives compile. Any idea how this could be accomplished?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a method on the superclass in a self-typed trait in scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849626/calling-a-method-on-the-superclass-in-a-self-typed-trait-in-scala)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is the answer I was looking for. Thank you Shadowlands for pointing me in the right direction with Scala's `abstract override` feature.

```
trait Abstract extends Result {
    abstract override def userRepr = "abstract " + super.userRepr
}

abstract class Result {
    def userRepr: String = "wtv"
}

case class ValDefResult(name: String) extends Result {
    override def userRepr = name
}

val a = new ValDefResult("asd") with Abstract
a.userRepr
```

Live code is available here: http://www.scalakata.com/52536cc2e4b0b1a1c4daa4a4

Sorry for the confusing example code, I am writing a library that deals with the Scala AST and was not inspired enough to change the names.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if you are in a position to make the following changes, but the effect you want can be achieved by introducing an extra trait (I'll call it `Repr`), and using `abstract override` in the `Abstract` trait:

```
trait Repr {
    def userRepr: String
}

abstract class Result extends Repr {
    def userRepr: String = "wtv"
}

case class ValDefResult(name: String) extends Result {
    override def userRepr = name
}

trait Abstract extends Repr { self: Result =>
    abstract override def userRepr = "abstract-" + super.userRepr // 'super.' works now
}
```

Your example usage now gives:

```
scala> val a = new ValDefResult("asd") with Abstract
a: ValDefResult with Abstract = ValDefResult(asd)

scala> a.userRepr
res3: String = abstract-asd
```

Comment: Although, I don't think I need to add the Repr trait to my particular situation, thx for pointing me in the right direction with the abstract override feature in Scala. I found this article explaining the feature: http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html

Comment: Very nice solution but providing an even lower base trait called `Repr` to contain the method which needs to be overriden, well played

Answer (score 9):

`abstract override` is the mechanism, aka stackable traits. It's worth adding that linearization counts, because that's what determines what `super` means.

This question is a great addendum to [the canonical Q&A on self-type vs extension](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1990948/1296806).

Where the inheritance is ambiguous with self-types:

```
scala> trait Bar { def f: String = "bar" }
defined trait Bar

scala> trait Foo { _: Bar => override def f = "foo" }
defined trait Foo

scala> new Foo with Bar { }
<console>:44: error: <$anon: Foo with Bar> inherits conflicting members:
  method f in trait Foo of type => String  and
  method f in trait Bar of type => String
(Note: this can be resolved by declaring an override in <$anon: Foo with Bar>.)
              new Foo with Bar { }
                  ^
```

Then obviously, you can choose:

```
scala> new Foo with Bar { override def f = super.f }
res5: Foo with Bar = $anon$1@57a68215

scala> .f
res6: String = bar

scala> new Foo with Bar { override def f = super[Foo].f }
res7: Foo with Bar = $anon$1@17c40621

scala> .f
res8: String = foo
```

or

```
scala> new Bar with Foo {}
res9: Bar with Foo = $anon$1@374d9299

scala> .f
res10: String = foo
```