# Is it possible to call an overridden method from self type?

Tags: scala

Consider this:

```
 class Foo { def foo = "foo" }
 trait Bar { self: Foo =>
    override def foo = "bar"
 }
```

I was pleasantly surprised to find out that this is possible, and works as expected:

```
new Foo with Bar foo
```

returns "bar". The question is whether it is possible for `Bar.foo` to invoke `Foo.foo`, like one would often do in the "ordinary" inheritance case.  `override def foo = super.foo + "bar"` does not work (says "foo is not a member of AnyRef), and neither does `override def foo = self.foo + "bar"` (it ends up just calling itself, and results in infinite recursion). 
I tried a few other combinations (like `self.Foo.foo`, `Foo.this.foo` etc.), but without any luck.

Is this just impossible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19237049/how-to-call-super-method-when-overriding-a-method-through-a-trait

Comment: @dmitry that does not answer my question: the answer there basically changes the design so that both the class and the trait extend a common parent, that defines the method being overridden. This is trivial, and not what I am after.

Comment: Well, here they say almost the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849626/calling-a-method-on-the-superclass-in-a-self-typed-trait-in-scala

Comment: @dmitry no, they don't. You are missing the point: that answer trivializes the problem again by making `OtherStuff` extend `Foo`. The question is about overriding a method in the _self type_, not in _superclass_.

Comment: I see that, @Dima. But it may mean that direct way to achieve what you want does not exist, and not trivializing.

Comment: @dmitry well, that's exactly the question, whether that way exists ... It just seems odd that one is allowed to override a method, but not to reference the original version.

Answer (score 5):

No. It is impossible to call overridden method from a self type.

Firstly the trait `Bar` is not a successor of class `Foo` so it is not possible using `super.foo`.

And secondly it is also not possible using `self.foo` since `self` is actually of type `Bar with Foo`. It can be shown by printing the program after `typer`:

```
$ scalac -Xprint:typer test.scala
[[syntax trees at end of                     typer]] // test.scala
package <empty> {
  class Foo extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): Foo = {
      Foo.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def foo: String = "foo"
  };
  abstract trait Bar extends scala.AnyRef { self: Bar with Foo => 
    def /*Bar*/$init$(): Unit = {
      ()
    };
    override def foo: String = "bar"
  };
  class FooBar extends Foo with Bar {
    def <init>(): FooBar = {
      FooBar.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  object TestApp extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>(): TestApp.type = {
      TestApp.super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val a: FooBar = new FooBar();
      scala.this.Predef.println(a.foo)
    }
  }
}
```

So with `self.foo` you are trying to access the method `foo` of the trait `Bar`. Such behavior matches the [Scala Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) (PDF):

> The sequence of template statements may be prefixed with a formal
>   parameter definition and an arrow, e.g. x =>, or x: T =>. If a formal
>   parameter is given, it can be used as an alias for the reference this
>   throughout the body of the template. If the formal parameter comes
>   with a type T, this definition affects the self type S of the
>   underlying class or object as follows: Let C be the type of the class
>   or trait or object defining the template. If a type T is given for the
>   formal self parameter, S is the greatest lower bound of T and C. If no
>   type T is given, S is just C. Inside the template, the type of this is
>   assumed to be S.

It is possible to access the method using reflection but I think that it is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any particular syntax to disentangle the base class and the mixed-in trait.
There is, however, an easy solution to achieve the result manually by distinguishing the overridden method from the default implementation in the base class:

```
class Foo { def foo = defaultFoo; def defaultFoo = "foo" }
trait Bar { self: Foo => override def foo = self.defaultFoo + "bar" }
```

As expected

```
new Foo with Bar foo == "foobar"
new Foo foo == "foo"
```

Comment: Well, if I could change `Foo`, there would be a bunch of possibilities available (starting with the obvious - make it extend a super-trait, common with `Bar`). The problem arises when once needs to do it without modifying `Foo`.

Comment: I see, so this is the root of your problem in fact. Sorry for not catching that. Is it a requirement that `Foo with Bar` has exactly the same interface as `Foo`?

Comment: Yeah ... :) The idea is to "pimp" `Foo` with `Bar`  transparently to the downstream code, that will still be using it as just `Foo`

Answer (score 0):

You make your trait extend `Foo` instead of using the self type:

```
class Foo {def foo = "foo"}
trait Bar extends Foo {
  override def foo = super.foo + "bar"
}
new Foo with Bar foo // barfoo
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12854994/2032064).

Comment: Well, if I made it extend Foo, that would make it a different problem, wouldn't it? I mean, it would have nothing to do with calling an overridden method fro self-type, which is what I was asking about ...

Comment: Well, if I were alibistic, I could propose declaring `Foo` as the self type for `Bar` in addition to inheriting it. Then you would technically be calling an overriden method from self type ;)

Comment: But the main point was to solve your declared problem: "The idea is to 'pimp' Foo with Bar transparently to the downstream code, that will still be using it as just Foo".

Comment: I just wonder, do you really think I did not know about being able to extend `Foo` :) Obviously, that is NOT "the main point" ...

Comment: (1) I had no idea, you know how it works on SO..., (2) it was the main point of my answer, (3) sorry I don't have a better answer other than Daniel's, I'll still leave my answer here for future reference